# Circles equation if two points are known.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, circles

This is an attempt to clarify a question I have.

[image]

$P$ can be anywhere on the circle. $P_1,P_2$ are there to show the only two angles, $\theta$ and $180-\theta$, between $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. $\vec{u}=\vec{QP}, \vec{v}=\vec{SP}$

This is the equation for the circle with a specific $\lambda$ when S and Q are known: $$\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}-\lambda(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})=0$$
This can be shown if you calculate it with the specific x- and y-values: $$x^2-(x_1+x_2+\lambda[y_1-y_2])x+y^2-(y_1+y_2+\lambda[x_2-x_1])y+x_1x_2+y_1y_2-\lambda(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)=0$$

I can clearly se that it is an equation for a circle with the center in $(\frac{x_1+x_2+\lambda(y_1-y_2)}{2}, \frac{y_1+y_2+\lambda(x_2-x_1)}{2})$, where $(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}, \frac{y_1+y_2}{2})$ is the midpoint of $\vec{QS}$,
and $\frac{\lambda}{2}\begin{bmatrix}y_1-y_2\\x_2-x_1\end{bmatrix}$ is a perpendicular vector to $\vec{QS}$.

My problem is that $$\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=\sin{\theta}|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|$$ $$\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=\pm\cos{\theta}|\vec{u}||\vec{v}|$$ depending on the angle between the vectors being either $\theta$ or $180-\theta$. How can $$\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}-\lambda(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})=0\Leftrightarrow\pm\cos{\theta}-\lambda\sin{\theta}=0\Leftrightarrow\pm1-\lambda\tan{\theta}=0\Leftrightarrow\lambda\tan{\theta}=\pm1$$represent a unique circler for $\theta\not=90\Leftrightarrow\lambda\not=0$. The $\pm1$ gives us two possible circles doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By translating and rotating, we can adopt a coordinate system in which $Q$ is the origin and $S$ lies on the $y$-axis. The intuition is that we can then choose the $x$-axis to the right, or reflect it to the left. That’s how we can get two circles.

In terms of the equation, we have $x_1 = x_2 = y_1 = 0$ so
$$
  x^2 + \lambda y_2 x - y_2 y + y^2 = 0
$$
or
$$
  \left( x + \frac{\lambda y_2}{2} \right)^2
  +
  \left( y - \frac{ y_2 }{2} \right)^2
  =
  r^2
$$
where $r$ accumulates the constant terms.
The two circles arise from $\lambda > 0$ versus $\lambda < 0$.

Note that
$$
  \vec{u} \times \vec{v} =  \sin(\theta) | \vec{u} | |\vec{v} |
$$
if $\theta$ is the angle from $\vec{u}$ to $\vec{v}$ on the range from 0 degrees to 360 degrees.  So if you want to restrict $\theta$ to being acute then there’s a $\pm$ factor (just as for the dot product).

Comment: Yes, $tan{\theta}$ is constant for every unique circle and $\pm1$ means the two circles mirrored in the line QS. But through solving the equation with coordinates I get the equation for a unique circle, how can that be?

Comment: Let's take the example $\lambda=1$. From $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}-\vec{u}\times\vec{v}$ we would get $(x+\frac{y_2}{2})^2+(y-\frac{y_2}{2})^2=2(\frac{y_2}{2})^2$. My confusion comes from the fact that  $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}-\vec{u}\times\vec{v}=0$ is not true for any points on the circle that have negative x-values since $-\cos{\theta}-\sin{\theta}\ne \cos{\theta}-\sin{\theta}$ for  $\theta\ne 90$. I know that I am missing something, because clearly the equation give a unique circle, I just can't see where in the equation I am wrong.

Comment: @Partick I think I just got it. Thank you so much. This has bothered me so long and I feel so relieved to understand my mistake.

Comment: You’re very welcome, glad I could be of some help.

Comment: It was the fact that the cross product changes sing as well.